# How to integrate liveperson chatbot into a customised webpage

Tags: html, liveperson

I want to integrate the LivePerson bot into a customized HTML page. Where do I get a script tag for integrating chatbot as we do in the ms bot framework?[image] something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag is available from the LivePerson web application.

Log in, pull down the menu under your username, select 'web tag'.

https://knowledge.liveperson.com/getting-started-add-the-liveperson-tag-to-your-website.html